# Detect selected language in Inno Setup [Code]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I want to download file with IDP plugin, but I need to choose the file in function of language. Example: installing in English and Spanish and the files are `myfile_x86_eng.exe` and `myfile_x86_spa.exe`.
I don't know nothing about Pascal and I've searched the internet and Stack Overflow without finding results.

I need something like this:

```
#include ".\Idp.iss"

[Languages]
Name: "English"; MessagesFile: "compiler: Languages\English.isl";
Name: "Spanish"; MessagesFile: "compiler: Languages\Spanish.isl";
```

```pascal
[Code]
Procedure InitializeWizard(): string;
Var
  Language: string;
Begin
  Language: = ExpandConstant('{param:LANG}');
  If Language = 'English' then
  Begin
    IdpAddFile(
      'https://myweb.com/myfile_x86_eng.exe',
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myfile_x86_eng.exe'));
  End
    Else
  If Language = 'Spanish' then
  Begin
    IdpAddFile(
      'https://myweb.com/myfile_x86_esp.exe',
      ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myfile_x86_spa.exe'));
  End;
End;
```

Other way can be make a language variable like this `myfile_x86_{lang}.exe` or something similar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`ActiveLanguage` function](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=isxfunc_activelanguage):

```pascal
if ActiveLanguage = 'English' then
begin
  IdpAddFile(
    'https://www.example.com/myfile_x86_eng.exe',
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myfile_x86_eng.exe'));
end
  else
if ActiveLanguage = 'Spanish' then
begin
  IdpAddFile(
    'https://www.example.com/myfile_x86_esp.exe', 
    ExpandConstant('{tmp}\myfile_x86_spa.exe'));
end;
```